# How do I get the gender of a person (IMDbpy)

Tags: python, imdbpy

How do I get gender of a person in a movie using IMDbPy? (I mainly want to find out if they're an actor or actress)

I know it's in their database or something but I don't know how to get it, right now I'm using a separate gender api but it's probably less reliable/slower